# Replacing the Remove Icon from FileInput in react-admin

Tags: react-admin

In the FileInput component, when a file has been dropped in the drop zone, it appears below the zone with a remove icon that I'd like to change (it's a wrong-way sign and I find it a bit hard to understand. I'd like to replace it with a simple trash icon).

How could I do that? I haven't seen any props related to that in the [documentation](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Inputs.html#fileinput).

Thanks

Comment: I think the icon you are talking about is set here https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/blob/master/packages/ra-ui-materialui/src/input/FileInputPreview.tsx#L57 It doesn't look user configurable, so you might have to write your own FileInput/FileInputPreview components

Comment: thanks @DoctorAgon . That's what we ended up doing.